# What would be the correct way to go about subnetting an IP address for two networks?

Tags: ipv4, subnet, networking, ip-address

I am struggling with how to proceed with this. I have started by converting the IP address into binary. If somebody could just give me a push in the right direction I would appreciate it!

There are two networks:

Network one has:

55 PCs,
4 printers,
2 wireless access points,
Interconnection devices,
Router

Network two has:

26 PCs,
2 printers,
2 wireless access points,
Interconnection devices,
Router

The given IP address is 172.16.0.0/24 and that needs to be subnetted and then the network devices need to be configured.

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains all about it.

Comment: [This question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers) and answers will explain it all to you.